# Detecting number of users (tabs) visiting the current page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have a very simple interface that only displays number 0 initially.

What I want to achieve is that whenever a new user visits my web page, I want to increment that number by 1.

So, if there are two users (or two tabs) visiting my web page at the same time, both tabs should display the number 2.

Is there any way for me to achieve this using Javascript or React?

Answer (score 0):

to track the number of connected users you should use back-end part as well , to achieve live data update on the page without refreshing users page you can implement web sockets protocol.